# When running resque, how do you launch workers on a server in a production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

Do you launch the works via a cron job?  And would that cron job just call the task using rake?

Any other suggestions or usage patterns greatly appreciated.

When you launch the worker, does it stay running waiting or do you have to run them each time and then the worker exits.

Answer (score 1):

I have my workers started via an upstart script which is then restarted after each deployment by capistrano. There's another similar question here which has a lot of other ways as well...

[How to deploy resque workers in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732415/how-to-deploy-resque-workers-in-production)