# How to just start 1 production Resque worker from Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, background-process, resque

I've got Redis/Resque installed but I'm having a hard time starting/restarting it from Capistrano when I deploy.

My needs are fairly simple: I only have 1 queue, only need 1 worker, and I'm not using monit or god.

Based on [this blog post](http://fhwang.net/2011/02/13/The-nuts-and-bolts-of-configuring-Resque-and-resque-web-for-a-production-Rails-app), my deploy.rb has this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  task :restart_resque do 
    pid_file = "#{shared_path}/pids/resque.pid" 
    run "test -f #{pid_file} && cd #{current_path} && kill -s QUIT `cat #{pid_file}` || rm -f #{pid_file}"
    run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE='*' VERBOSE=1 nohup rake environment resque:work& > #{shared_path}/log/resque.log && echo $! > #{pid_file}"
  end

end

after 'deploy:restart', 'deploy:restart_resque'
```

My resque.rake file (based on the Railscast) has:

```
require "resque/tasks"  

task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

When I `cap deploy`, everything seems to work but there are no workers running when I look at resque-web ...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732415/how-to-deploy-resque-workers-in-production) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/797301) for quite a few suggestions.